# Telnet connexion with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, telnet

I'm trying to access a telnet data stream with MATLAB.

The only toolbox I found which seemed to do this is the TCPIP toolbox.

Sadly enough, I can't establish the *discussion* between the two machines.

Code used :

```
t = tcpip(IP, PORT);
fopen(t);
fwrite(t, MyTelnetCommand);
response = fread(t, 1)
```

I hoped response would be the `MyTelnetCommand` response, but I always get :

```
Warning: Unsuccessful read:  The specified amount of data was
not returned within the Timeout period. 

response =

    Empty matrix: 1-by-0
```

Is there a way to handle what I'm trying to achieve ?

Comment: No answers... Is it something doable ? Maybe I try to do something Matlab is not designed for. Please let me know ! I'll ask Mathworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the solution with the support of Mathworks.

First, it's better to convert the command in double:

```
MyTelnetCommandConverted = double(MyTelnetCommand)';
```

Second, do not use `fwrite()` for text command but `fprintf()`, according to the documentation ([fwrite](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/serial.fwrite.html) and [fprintf](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/serial.fprintf.html)).

Finally, one should wait for getting the answer of the server:

```
while(tCmd.BytesAvailable<=0)
    drawnow
end
response = fread(tCmd, tCmd.BytesAvailable);
char(response')
```

or

```
while(tCmd.BytesAvailable<=0)
    drawnow
end
response = fscanf(tCmd, '%s', tCmd.BytesAvailable)
```

So the comprehensive code is :

```
tCmd = tcpip(ip, portCmd);
set(tCmd,'InputBufferSize',buffSize); % buffSize = 1000000
set(tCmd,'OutputBufferSize',buffSize);

fopen(tCmd);

MyTelnetCommand = '(sendCommand cmd_Start 0 -1 1)';
MyTelnetCommandConverted = double(MyTelnetCommand)';
fprintf(tCmd, MyTelnetCommandConverted);

while(tCmd.BytesAvailable<=0)
    drawnow
end
response = fscanf(tCmd, ,'%s', tCmd.BytesAvailable)

fclose(tCmd);
```